# How to change sub-caption to small font from capital letters?

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption

I used `\usepackage{caption}` and `\usepackage{subcaption}` respectively for the captions. now when i generated the pdf i get the subcaption as

> `(A),(B),(C)`

. I need all of them in small letters like

> `(a)(b)(c)`

and so on..
Where is should make changes? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome on tex.stackexchange.com. Can you please provide a minimal working example (MWE) start with `\documentclass{}` and ends with `\end{document}` that reproduce the error/problem you need to solve? Thanks

Comment: yes, i am using \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{jihmsp}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `amsart` class you can directly get the small-case subcaptions.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[]{0.48\textwidth}
            \caption{A}
            \label{FigPractice1} 
        \end{subfigure}\par
        \begin{subfigure}[]{0.48\textwidth}
            \caption{B}
            \label{FigPractice2} 
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{a caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to set the font caption to small-case. This is an option in `subcaption` package. You must set the option `font=small` to achieve what you want. But AFAIK, the small-case is the stock option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering\large A
            \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering\large B
            \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, your second solution only worked after adding `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}` like in your first solution.

Comment: @JustBasti without knowing your preamble, it is difficult to infer.